# Enum comboBox lists every item twice

Tags: winforms, enums, combobox

I have a custom ComboBox in WinForms that is supposed to display an enumeration. Basically, I derived from ComboBox and in the constructor, I load the items from the enum.

The problem is that, even though at the end of the process it says the count of items is the same as the enum item count, the visual representation shows as if the same items were added twice. In other words, if my enum had values Value1 and Value2 the ComboBox says it has two values but when dropping down it shows Value1, Value2, Value1, Value2 as if I had added them twice.

```
public class EnumComboBox : ComboBox
{
   public EnumComboBox() : base()
   {
      foreach (MyEnum p in Enum.GetValues(typeof(MyEnum)) {
          base.Items.Add(p);
      }
      SelectedIndex = 0;
   }

}
```

As you can see in the code, in the constructor the items are added ONCE but they are listed twice. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Add a breakpoint on the line `base.Items.Add(p);` and debug your code to see how many times each item is added. E.g. if your code is paused 3 times, and you have 3 items to be added, then each item was added once.

Comment: I did put a Console.WriteLine and it shows every item added ONCE. At the end I also outputted Items.Count and it was the correct amount  (2 not 4).

Comment: Is your `ComboBox`' list of items empty in the form designer before you run the program?

Answer (score 1):

Rather than in the Constructor the manner to get it to behave properly was to leave the constructor empty and move the insertion code to the OnCreate method:

```
protected override void OnCreateControl()
{
    if (!DesignMode) {
        foreach (MyEnum p in Enum.GetValues(typeof(MyEnum))) {
            Items.Add(p);
        }
        SelectedIndex = 0;
    }
}
```